# get_lock, release_lock in mysql

Tags: mysql

What is the actual purpose and why using get_lock, release_lock functions in mysql?
I read the official documentation, but I don't get it clearly. What actually happen when do SELECT GET_LOCK('lock1', 10). Please explain me.

When we using them and why need to use them.

Comment: Did you read the manual? Because it pretty clear in there https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock

Comment: It's useful when you need finer-grained locking than you get with just the `LOCK TABLE` statement.

Comment: @RaymondNijland He says he read the documentation but didn't understand it.

Comment: Geuss i missed that @Barmar .. Topicstarter not sure want you want to do or for what you need it. i never have needed `GET_LOCK` like the Caution says in the manual it's looks like a wierd statement..  Besides when i read simulate record locks i more tended to use real record transaction based locking like innodb supports with `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`

Comment: They are just fancy user - controlled locking that your application(s) may use e.g. for implementing some kind of distributed transaction.  (I may be wrong, but) I believe they were especially handy 30 years ago(?) when MySQL had only table - level locking, which was quite a challenge in general.

Comment: Thanks all. So GET_LOCK is not a good option?

Comment: I'd say in most of cases - yes. But if you can guarantee that all your software uses the same conventions - GET_LOCK probably may be good solutions in some rare scenarios . E.g. if daemons will attempt to lock predefined lock before starting DB work - you will have a nice tool to temporarily disable startup of one or all  those daemons e.g. for maintanence, etc.